# Electron Quick Start in NodeJS Child Process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, child-process

I am trying to combine a Gulp setup with debugging electron-quick-start, and I am trying to close and re-open Electron when changes occur in my source files, which I implemented with `child_process.spawn`, and launching it works fine, and closing seems fine but the electron application remains active and a new one is openend up - even though if it runs in its own main process, sending the `SIGINT` using `cmd+C` will close the application shell as well. I have simplified my code to the following snippet, and added a countdown just to be sure that it wasn't the timing that was problematic. Also, `electron-quick-start`s whole repository is actually inside the `./app/` folder, as my Gulp will live outside of it, it just outputs to inside the applications resources folder.

```js
function destroyElectron(){
 
  return new Promise(function( resolve, reject ){
 
    if( electron ){
  
      console.log( 'Closing Electron...' );
 
      electron.on( 'close', () => {
    
        console.log( 'Electron Event: Close' );
    
        resolve();
    
      });
      electron.on( 'exit', () => {
    
        console.log( 'Electron Event: Exit' );
    
        resolve();
    
      });
   
      electron.kill( 'SIGINT' );
      electron = null;
   
    } else {
  
      resolve();
  
    }
 
  });
 
}
function startElectron(){
 
  destroyElectron().then(() => {
 
    console.log( 'Starting Electron...' );
 
    electron = spawn( 'npm', [ 'start' ], { stdio: 'inherit', cwd: './app' } );
    electron.on( 'close', destroyElectron );
 
  });
 
}

var spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawn;
var electron;
var count = 0;

startElectron();

var interval = setInterval(function(){

  if( ++count == 10 ){
  
    clearInterval( interval );
    destroyElectron().then(() => {
   
      console.log( 'Electron is destroyed' );
   
    });
 
  } else {
  
    console.log( 10 - count );
  
  }
 
}, 1000 );
```

Is there a reason why ending it manually in the command line has a different effect than sending the signal manually? Can I close the full Electron Quick Start application running in the child process?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting confuse in your question but I want to share you my gulp file which I used for watch my project file and reload app :)

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var electron = require('electron-connect').server.create();

gulp.task('start',function(){
  electron.start();
})

gulp.task('serve', function () {
  // Start browser process
  electron.start();

  // Restart browser process
  gulp.watch('app.js', electron.restart);

  // Reload renderer process
   gulp.watch(["./src/*.*","./src/**/*.*"], electron.reload);
});

gulp.task('reload:browser', function () {
  // Restart main process
  electron.restart();
});

gulp.task('reload:renderer', function () {
  // Reload renderer process
  electron.reload();
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, the issue I am trying to solve however is that I want to have my gulp in a parent directory, running the watch tasks etc... While all the electron components etc get nicely separated in a subdirectory called `app`. I am trying to get this `electron-connect` working, but it seems to require electron existing in the same directory...